# How can I create temp table and select it in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

Like the question title, how can I do that? I'm using Oracle SQL.

```sql
begin
-- create temp table here
-- sql query
   -- select temp table here
end;
```

Comment: Hint: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: May i ask why you would use temp tables. what is the end goal you have in mind?.In sql server having temp tables is a usual practice. but this would not be the right way to do things in Oracle

Comment: @George Joseph I need to create a temp table to store all records of 2 tables then start to select these records in my condition query.

Comment: See whether a view or a CTE helps. I agree with @George - in Oracle, there's rarely need for temporary tables.

Comment: Rather than asking how to implement a very specific solution that you believe is the correct one, it would be better to give us a sample example with a limited dataset to illustrate your problem. That way you'll get *the best* solution. I agree with the comments above that there are probably easier solutions than a temporary table, but ... no way to know with that code snippet you posted.

Comment: More often than not, using temp tables is the wrong approach

Comment: @Littlefoot, in Oracle `GLOBAL TEMPORARY` tables are quite common I would say. If you mean by "temporary table" a table which is created temporary and dropped after usage" then your are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `Global temporary table` outside the procedure and use it in your procedure.

The data in a global temporary table is private, such that data inserted by a session can only be accessed by that session. The session-specific rows in a global temporary table can be preserved for the whole session, or just for the current transaction.

You can learn more about GTT from [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables).

But, looking at your problem It seems that you can use the `private temporary table`, that can be created in your session by you and deleted(automatically) once the session/transaction is completed.

But it is available from Oracle 18c onwards.

You can learn more about Private temporary table from [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/private-temporary-tables-18c).